# Transparent icon in start menu for universal app

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp

I'm developing a universal app. I have a list of icons in the manifest. The icon on the taskbar is fine, transparency works.

The start menu icon doesn't have transparent edges.

[No edges.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDHdg.png)

[The list of icons that I have.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKkZH.png)

How would I make the edges transparent? Should I add any other icons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design as the background (behind the tile itself) may be colored quite differently. In the start menu, there's a dark background whereas there's a white background in the Cortana search. Maybe try sending MS your wishes via the feedback app :)

Comment: Do you know how some icons show unplated? Like if I search for Chrome, it shows up transparent?

Comment: @Dunkan Chrome is not a windows app, it's a native win32 executable.

Comment: The way this is implemented right now makes me cry. Thanks, I would upvote your answer but I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like that it's by design, as you can see, default Windows Apps behave the same too, even those which use transparent color for their logo (like Calculator, Mail, etc).

However, If you set background color of logo and tile to "transparent" (in app manifest) your app icon may get displayed in start menu with transparent background in some circumstances like when Windows is in hight contrast theme.