# UWP Tile Background Color Not Working

Tags: background, win-universal-app, tile

I set the background color in the app manifest to black but the tile still shows blue in the app list and transparent when pinned to the start screen. The tile color is changed in the IDE (VS) but not when I run it in the phone emulator.

[image]

There is a similar question and answer: [Windows 8 Live Tile Icon Background Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755773/windows-8-live-tile-icon-background-color), but it is specifically for Windows 8 and actually says you can set it to anything which is not true as I found out.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid reason to write up your own Q&A. Best though, to stick with the normal Q & A format, and the facts of the problem, without additional noise. I've edited your posts into shape, I think, but you could still tweak the question to make it more likely that people with this problem would find it. A code example would be a great addition.

Comment: Tyvm for the formatting and advice. I do not have code to show but I added an image of the issue and where I was setting the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the value must be a hex value, which is not very clear in the VS IDE.

In fact setting the background color to "black" in the app manifest will show the tiles in the IDE as having black backgrounds and it will even make the tile background black when ran as a desktop app; but when run in the phone emulator it was completely ignoring the defined background color.

Changing it to `#000000` finally resolved my problem.

Comment: Any idea how to make it transparent?

Comment: I do not believe that is possible since they require a 6 digit hex value #RRGGBB. It does not support the alpha channel. I have read in several posts that you can change it at runtime but I have not personally done that. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37583687/transparent-tile-but-colored-icon-for-the-windows-store
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091730/transparent-icon-in-start-menu-for-universal-app

Comment: how about just typing "transparent" ?