What is a Win32 "app's registered background color?"
Reading the description for SIIGBF_ICONBACKGROUND, it says:

SIIGBF_ICONBACKGROUND (0x00000080)
Introduced in Windows 8. If returning an icon, paint a background
using the associated app's registered background color.

What is the "associated app's registered background color"?
When I pass this flag to IShellItemImageFactory::GetImage(), the background is painted green.  I want to paint the background white.
I tried setting the background brush, but it had no effect.
let brush = CreateSolidBrush(COLORREF(0xFFFFFF));
SetClassLongPtrW(hwnd, GCLP_HBRBACKGROUND, brush.0 as isize);


https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/app-background-color-changed-to-green-how-to-reset/eb702e0c-af1c-449a-8e87-66f2fb9a6463

That probably refers to the uap:VisualElements element of an App package manifest. The package manifest was introduced for the UWP but is (seemingly) used for Desktop application deployment as well. I wouldn't know why the BackgroundColor attribute was useful (outside of XBox' or Windows 10 Mobile's UI).

That's the same concept as the "tile background" talked about here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503505/uwp-tile-background-color-not-working. A file type might be associated with an app and that app has a "background color", aka "tile background" (Windows property key PKEY_Tile_Background for items in shell:AppsFolder https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/store/find-aumid?tabs=explorer). Anyway, you can determine what this color will be for a given file/app but you won't be able to define it yourself at execution time.
